# Converting javascript data to json file

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using a TradingView widget to pull charts and the data is coded in this format:

```
symbols: {          
  Equities: ['H&P', 'Google'], 
 }, 
 symbols_description: { 
    'H&P': ' BATS:HP ', 
    'Google': 'BATS:GOOG',      
}
```

I want to convert the symbols and the symbols description into dynamic code using json. I'm struggling on how to use a json file instead of hard coded. Thanks in advance. The entire widget code is:

```
new TradingView.MiniWidget({
    container_id: 'tv-miniwidget-2', tabs: ['Equities'], 
    symbols: {          
       Equities: ['H&P', 'Google'], 
    }, 
    symbols_description: {
       'H&P': ' BATS:HP ', 
       'Google': 'BATS:GOOG',
    }, 
    width: 240, 
    large_chart_url: 'http://www.futuresmag.com/page/interactive-charts',
    gridLineColor: "#e9e9ea",
    fontColor: "#83888D",
    underLineColor: "#dbeffb",
    trendLineColor: "#4bafe9",                 
    height: 400,
    locale: "en"
    });
```

Comment: you want data from json file or this json is already available in your code?

Comment: I can create the json file, just don't know how to use it. It really doesn't have to be json, I'm creating the file myself so it can be in any format.

Answer (score 0):

Build data in steps, not all at once

```
let options = {
  container_id: 'tv-miniwidget-2', tabs: ['Equities'],  
  width: 240, 
  large_chart_url: 'http://www.futuresmag.com/page/interactive-charts',
  gridLineColor: "#e9e9ea",
  fontColor: "#83888D",
  underLineColor: "#dbeffb",
  trendLineColor: "#4bafe9",                 
  height: 400,
  locale: "en"
}
// data format
let jsonData = {
  symbols: {          
    Equities: ['H&P', 'Google'], 
  },
  symbols_description: { 
    'H&P': ' BATS:HP ', 
    'Google': 'BATS:GOOG',      
  }
} // get data from server through ajax request or whatever you need
options.symbols = jsonData.symbols
options.symbols_description = jsonData.symbols_description

new TradingView.MiniWidget(options)
```

Comment: in given case it needs to have symbols and symbols_description keys so the format in your question in first code field

Comment: I'm trying to use this, but it isn't working:    symbols: {          
  Equities: ['H&P', 'Google'],  
}, 
symbols_description: { 
 'H&P': ' BATS:HP ', 
 'Google': 'BATS:GOOG',     
}

Comment: added data structure into answer

Comment: With the data added it works, I copied the format to the json file and it doesn't work. I have checked the path and it is correct.

Comment: With the edited answer, if you remove the hard coded data and instead go with let jsonData = <?php echo $jsondata ?>, where I use $jsondata variable in my php code when I create the json, it works.

Answer (score 0):

To load a `json` file in a browser, you typically take the following steps :

1. Make an Ajax call to your `json` file
2. Parse the `json` file once it's been received
3. Do something with the content of the file once it's parsed

Here's some demo code for how to do that without using any library:

```
var getJSON = function(url, successHandler, errorHandler) {
    // 1. Make an Ajax call to your json file
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('get', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var status, data;
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            status = xhr.status;
            if (status == 200) {
                // 2. Parse the json file once it's been received
                data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                successHandler && successHandler(data);
            } else {
                errorHandler && errorHandler(status);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
};

getJSON('widgetdata.json', function(data) {
    // 3. Do something with the content of the file once it's parsed
    var tradingView = new TradingView.MiniWidget(data);
}, function(status) {
    // Error handling goes here
});
```